# Changing File Structure

Tags: directory

A lot of times when I'm unzipping files, I'll get a messed up directory structure that looks like /home/bob/myfolder/myfolder/otherstuff. Where the only thing that the first myfolder contains is another directory named myfolder.

How could I collapse this path to get /home/bob/myfolder/otherstuff? I.e. I want to remove the useless in-between link.

Comment: Not really a question. I am assuming you know how to use `cd` , `mkdir`, `cp`, `mv` etc....

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /home/bob
mv myfolder myfolder1
mv myfolder1/myfolder .
rm myfolder1
```

Or just cut/paste in a file browser.